# My wordpress website admin panel loads very slow, what can i do about that?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, server-load

I am having a very slow load time for long time now, I read absolutely everything that I could about how to speed up my WordPress website hosted on azure, However there things that I am not capable to do because I don't have the right knowledge.

I do aware that my WordPress website have allot of plugins installed and some off them I developed myself, but even if they are the cause of the slow speed of the website I **can't do much about that, because I really need them.**

I tried to scale my website (On azure) to much better performance and it didn't help at all. I am not a professional but how can it be that php and html take so much time to load with such a good server ?
I ran Google web speed performance test and the main cause of slowness was caused by server response time that I guess have something to do because the amount of PHP tasks my website does.

I also tried to increase the php memory of WordPress to 128M and it didn't help (my PHP version is 5.6).

So basically I am looking for a solution without disabling any of my plugins, something like upgrading the memory or the CPU or just "teach" WordPress to use the server performance at the best way, I mean if wordpress does work good without plugins so it should work  good with them also if you increase the server accordingly, Am I right ?!

Looking forward for your help I really need this and hopefully you will be enable to give me an answer that could fix that problem. Thanks ahead.

Comment: I suggest to disable all plugins and use a default theme. Then start to activate the theme and the plugins one by one until you detect where the problematic code is. At that point you are ready to start fixing/optimizing the code; if the problematic code can not be optimized, you will have to implement some kind of cache in order to not perform those tasks in every page load.

Comment: Related threads: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166727/how-can-i-speed-up-my-wp-admin-section/167014#167014 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166727/how-can-i-speed-up-my-wp-admin-section

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. If you don't want to disable any plugins, try to use the [P3 Profiler plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to identify the plugin or plugins that are slowing down your site.

If you don't want to run experiments on your live website, you should make a copy on a sub-domain (you can use the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin for this), make sure the second website is not accessible for anyone (use a htpassword or a password plugin to protect it), then use the P3 Profiles or just disable the plugins one by one to see which one has problems.

You can also use the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to identify slow queries, amount of memory used, HTTP requests and other things that slow down your website.

Comment: I see, so there is no other option but to check all the code in the plugins and to fix the problematic one ?

Comment: After you find the plugin that causes the slow down, you could try to check its code, but probably it will be easier to just replace it with another.